# Using Reactstrap: Unable to apply CSS styles to image for CarouselItem and how to use div instead of image

Tags: css, image, carousel, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am using reactstrap in my production website using react.js.

I wonder if someone could help me with implementing reactstrap carousel. I am trying to apply CSS to the image itself for CarouselItem but it is not getting applied. For CarouselItem there is a prop for src but because the full img tag is not used I'm not sure how to apply CSS to that. I wonder if someone could help me with that?

I am also building a slider with text but no images for a news feed using Carousel and I'm not sure how to setup the CarouselItems with a div of text instead of a img?

I would really appreciate some help with those two issues. New to reactstrap and amazing resource so trying to implement it in production.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show some examples with code what are you trying to do. It is likely that you are not specific enough to override bootstrap's settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve managed to solve this one. For anyone having the same problem then one solution is to over ride the bootstrap css for carousel classes. Those changes are then picked up by the carousel and the css is applied.

I haven’t solved the text carousel but that might not be possible yet with Reactstrap.

Hope this helps people having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a white background with black letters over it. Done